# Signed apk with command line and Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, android-keystore

I need to generate a signed apk of my android studio project with a shell script but I have problem to execute the task "assembleRelease".

In fact the problem is the following:

Case 1:

- cd myAndroidStudioProject
- ./gradlew assembleRelease
- apk is generated without problem

Case 2:

- myAndroidStudioProject/gradlew assembleRelease
- Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
  Keystore file not set for signing config release

I have test to set some params with my command (-p, -P) but It's not working.

Someone knows how to use gradlew command with absolute path?

Regards

Comment: is file referenced by `storeFile` in `signingConfigs` section of your build.gradle in expected place?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used something like `new File('relative/path/to/keystore')` in your build file. This is by definition (look at its JavaDoc) relative to the current working directory, so changes when you call `gradlew` from somewhere else.

Instead use `project.file('relative/path/to/keystore')`, or as `project` will be implicit just `file('relative/path/to/keystore')`, then it will work, no matter where you call `gradlew` from.